# Marginal probability multivariable case

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we have four random variables $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}$ and we have some joint probability mass function $P(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})$. What is  distribution of $P(x_{1})$ and $P(x_{1},x_{2})$ (assuming discrete case)?

Correct me if I am wrong:
$P(x_{1})=\sum_{x_{2}}\sum_{x_{3}}\sum_{x_{4}}P(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})$
$P(x_{1},x_{2})=\sum_{x_{3}}\sum_{x_{4}}P(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})$

Comment: When they are discrete you call them (joint) probability mass functions. When you are representing the dummy variable, you can just use the lower case. The general principle here is correct.

Comment: corrected. Y0u meant discrete variable n0t dummy, I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

$P_{X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ gives us the probability of observation $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$.

$P_{X_1}(x_1)$ is the probability of observing $X_1=x_1$ regardless of values of $X_2,X_3,X_4$, hence we sum them up.

Similarly for continuous case, we just have to integrate the other variables up.